# Inserting new lines into innerHTML output

Tags: javascript, html, tags, newline, line-breaks

If I were to have a string for a variable be `var text = "Hello World!"` and I wanted to place a new line after the word Hello, I know I can just create a new variable `var b = text.replace(" ", "\n");` and console.log(b) will show the text in 2 lines. (I also know there's multiple ways of doing this without using the replace method).

But I have a bunch of text from a document.getElementById("div").innerHTML that returns a bunch of script and img and more div tags, etc. When it writes this, it doesn't really do any spacing at all and just mushes all together, as many characters in a line as it can.

What would be a way that I can print out the contents of document.getElementById("div").innerHTML such that after the end of each tag `</script>` `</img>`, etc., it creates a new line for easier reading?
I tried doing replace for (">",">\n") but that didn't do anything which I'm assuming is because of the format that innerHTML is in, not actually a text string I assume.

Comment: Explain easier to read? The source code? What the Client sees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Alternative to `.innerHTML`

`.textContext` isn't perfect but you can use it fine in this case:

```
var text = document.getElementById("div").textContent;
```

---

### Solution

Replacing with newlines:

```
text.replace(/(img\/|script)\>/ig, '$1>\n')
```

---

With breaks:

```
text.replace(/(img\/|script)\>/gi, '$1>\<br/>')
```

---

### RegExp

```
(            <- Start capturing group
    img\/    <- Select img\
    |        <- OR
    script   <- Select script
)
\>           <- Matches > character
```

**`g`** is the global modifier. **`i`** is a case-insensitive modifier. The *`$1`* in the string is replaces the capture group.

Comment: What .textContext appeared to do in this case was eat a lot of the information inside the tags. The RegExp information was helpful though. I looked over RegExp a couple months back and have been trying to implement them as much as I can in code just to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

replace js command just replaces the first char, try this:

```
str.replace(/>/g, "><br>");
```

Comment: This was close to it. Using a global modifier with RegExp was what I was really missing but it worked when I replaced />/g with ">\n" and not "><br>"

Answer (score 1):

Get the correct Node and do this instead:

```
var b = text.replace(/\s+/, '<br />');
```

HTML treats new lines and white spaces as a single white space. Of course, if you just want the text to be easy for the user to ready and you know what the content is already, `<pre></pre>` may be your friend.